# Salesforce Site save new record

Tags: force.com-sites

I have a visualforce page that has a user sign up for a newsletter.
It inserts their information into a custom object "Individual"
The page uses the Individual standard controller and a redirect controller extension to redirect them to a thank you page on "save"

The code works when I preview it but doesn't insert a record from the site.
The page loads with all fields, all editable, and on "save" it redirects to the thank you page but no "Individual" record is created.

User has read, create, and edit access under "Public Access Settings", and all related fields visible under "Field-level security"

Redirect Controller Extension:

```
public without sharing class RedirectExtension {
    ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
    public String redirect {get; set;}

    public redirectExtension (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        standardController= stdController;
    }

    public PageReference SaveAndRedirect (){
        standardController.save();

        return new PageReference(redirect);
    }
}
```

VisualForcePage

```
<apex:page StandardController="Individual__c"  extensions="RedirectExtension" standardStylesheets="false" showheader="false" sidebar="false">

<script src="/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jquery}"/>

<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.EmilySalesforcecss}" />

<apex:form >
    <apex:inputHidden id="redirect-link" value="{!redirect}"/>


    <div id="background">
    </div>
        <div id="container" class="ui-corner-all">
            <div id="header" data-role="header" align="center">
                <h1 Style="font-size: 25px;">
                    <div align="center">
                        <apex:image url="{!$Resource.UGL_Logo}" width="175" height="175"/>
                        <br></br>
                        Newsletter Sign-Up
                    </div>
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Sign up to receive bimonthly LabNotes e-newsletter from Urban Green Lab. &nbsp;We'll keep you updated on our work and provide opportunities to get involved.
                </p>
            </div>
            <h2 Style="font-size: 15px;">
            <apex:pageBlock >

                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="individual-info"> 
                    <label class="required"><span class="assistiveText">*</span> = required field</label>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Individual__c.Name}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Individual__c.Address__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Individual__c.Addr2__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Individual__c.City__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Individual__c.State__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Individual__c.Zip_Code__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Individual__c.Email__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockButtons id="editButtons" location="top" rendered="true">
                   <apex:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Submit" action="{!SaveAndRedirect}" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </h2>
        </div>

</apex:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    InitPage();

    function InitPage(){
        $("[id*='redirect-link']").val('/apex/Newsletter_Thank_You');
    }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Looks like you have all possible configurations in place. Can you share your public site URL to have a look?

Comment: http://urbangreenlab.force.com/NewsletterSignUp

Comment: Please update the question with you VF page as well.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Use apex:pagemessages tag at beginning to discover if any errors on pages.

Comment: I've added the <apex:pagemessages /> tag. The preview still works as before (except that if i leave out required fields an error shows at the top of the page). However, now every time I submit on the public site it brings me to the "Authorization Required" page

Comment: Correction: no longer getting "Authorization Required" page. still not saving new records though, and no page messages on "submit" (except required field ones if they are missing)

Comment: You can debug as guest user and see logs if you see anything unexpected

Comment: Can you check if by mistake Site is not active yet?

Answer (score 0):

2 reasons for the error that I can think of (considering it is working properly on normal login)

1. Site is not active
2. Need to add the site VF page and related controllers as enabled VF pages / classes under public access settings profile

Ray

Comment: The site's "Active" checkbox is checked.

Both Newsletter_Sign_Up and Newsletter_Thank_You are enabled under "Enabled Visualforce Page Access" and the RedirectExtension is enabled under Enabled Apex Class Access

Comment: Damn then I am out of reasons. I need org to look into in such scenarios. Otherwise it becomes too difficult to gauge the reason

Comment: thanks anyway. I am also out of reasons. been trying different changes since yesterday and keep getting the same result.    
I added some debug logs and interestingly, the record does get an "id" assigned after update.   When i added a manual insert (rather than standard controller's save) and added a system.debug(indiv.id); I get a debug log entry with an id (|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|a011a000002YeaYAAS). But can't see a record

Comment: This is definitely related to permissions. If you think looking at org may be feasible option, then let me know, we can discuss over chat (as it sounds interesting)